# Spring Cloud Contract testing body does not match

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to test my multipart file upload API with Spring Cloud Contract testing.

But on the consumer side, my test is failing due to request body does not match.

But looking at the given error message, it's hard to me to understand why:

```
+[                                                Request was not matched
+[                                                =======================
+[ 
+[ -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+[ | Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
+[ -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+[                                                            |
+[ POST                                                       | POST
+[ /my-api/(\w|\W)+/objects                                   | /my-api/storage_id/objects
+[                                                            |
+[ Content-Type [matches] : multipart/form-data.*             | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;boundary=m82DlcHjsDnwxS
+[                                                            | BXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[ Accept [matches] : application/json.*                      | Accept: application/json
+[                                                            |
+[ .*--(.*)                                                  | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i                  <<<<< Body does not match
+[ Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myId"               | Content-Disposition:
+[ (Content-Type: .*                                         | form-data; name="myId"
+[ )?(Content-Transfer-Encoding: .*                          | Content-Type:
+[ )?(Content-Length: \d+                                    | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[ )?                                                        | Content-Length:
+[ ^\s*\S[\S\s]*                                             | 6
+[ --\1.*                                                     | someId
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Content-D
+[                                                            | isposition: form-data; name="myPath"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[                                                            | Content-Length:
+[                                                            | 8
+[                                                            | somePath
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Content
+[                                                            | -Disposition: form-data;
+[                                                            | name="ct"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[                                                            | Content-Length:
+[                                                            | 10
+[                                                            | text/plain
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Cont
+[                                                            | ent-Disposition: form-data; name="cs";
+[                                                            | filename="test"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | application/octet-stream
+[                                                            | test
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEf
+[                                                            | qQEMEsdX7i--
+[ .*--(.*)                                                  | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i                  <<<<< Body does not match
+[ Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myPath"             | Content-Disposition:
+[ (Content-Type: .*                                         | form-data; name="myId"
+[ )?(Content-Transfer-Encoding: .*                          | Content-Type:
+[ )?(Content-Length: \d+                                    | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[ )?                                                        | Content-Length:
+[ ^\s*\S[\S\s]*                                             | 6
+[ --\1.*                                                     | someId
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Content-D
+[                                                            | isposition: form-data; name="myPath"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[                                                            | Content-Length:
+[                                                            | 8
+[                                                            | somePath
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Content
+[                                                            | -Disposition: form-data;
+[                                                            | name="ct"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[                                                            | Content-Length:
+[                                                            | 10
+[                                                            | text/plain
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Cont
+[                                                            | ent-Disposition: form-data; name="cs";
+[                                                            | filename="test"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | application/octet-stream
+[                                                            | test
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEf
+[                                                            | qQEMEsdX7i--
+[ .*--(.*)                                                  | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i                  <<<<< Body does not match
+[ Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ct"                 | Content-Disposition:
+[ (Content-Type: .*                                         | form-data; name="myId"
+[ )?(Content-Transfer-Encoding: .*                          | Content-Type:
+[ )?(Content-Length: \d+                                    | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[ )?                                                        | Content-Length:
+[ ^\s*\S[\S\s]*                                             | 6
+[ --\1.*                                                     | someId
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Content-D
+[                                                            | isposition: form-data; name="myPath"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[                                                            | Content-Length:
+[                                                            | 8
+[                                                            | somePath
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Content
+[                                                            | -Disposition: form-data;
+[                                                            | name="ct"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | text/plain;charset=UTF-8
+[                                                            | Content-Length:
+[                                                            | 10
+[                                                            | text/plain
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i
+[                                                            | Cont
+[                                                            | ent-Disposition: form-data; name="cs";
+[                                                            | filename="test"
+[                                                            | Content-Type:
+[                                                            | application/octet-stream
+[                                                            | test
+[                                                            | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEf
+[                                                            | qQEMEsdX7i--
+[                                                            |
+[ -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, starting from this line:

```
.*--(.*)   | --m82DlcHjsDnwxSBXh7XEfqQEMEsdX7i  <<<<< Body does not match
```

It shows a mismatched request which is hard to understand why to me!

Any thoughts?

P.S:

Here is my producer pom dependent part:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <baseClassForTests>
                        com.backbase.cxs.cs.c3.BaseTest
                    </baseClassForTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here is the consumer part:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And I'm using spring-cloud dependencyManagement:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.SR4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know without seeing the groovy/yaml contract, but it could be that either your regex is somewhat off (like an extra space or something? It looked good on regex101.com) or perhaps you are matching on a hardcoded string ".*--(.*)" instead of a regex at all.

If you are using groovy, make sure you have

```
value(regex(".*--(.*)"))
```

instead of just

```
".*--(.*)"
```

not sure what the equivalent is in yaml.